# signInWithEmailAndPassword: getting auth/user-token-expired

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am using signInWithEmailAndPassword method in client sdk and getting auth/user-token-expired

It is happening when I am first calling revokeRefreshTokens and just after that using signInWithEmailAndPassword method to relogin user again.

I want to logout the user from all other devices.

I notice that after 30 sec signInWithEmailAndPassword again start working

I posted this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2201) on github -> firebase/firebase-js-sdk as well

Comment: I got it. NTP synchronized was off I change it now my code is working fine.